# Filter many-to-many relationsip - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

i have a dating website whose database is as follows

```
country (list of all countries)
-------    
id
name

users (It contains all types of users - Super Admin, Fronend user)
-----

id
role_id
name
email
password
country_id
active


user_profile(contains further details of frontend users)
------------

id
user_id
gender_id
photo
status
screenname
headline
location
sign
...and 12 more columns specific to frontend users


gender(specific to genders option - Male, Female, Gay, Prefer Not To Say, etc)
------

id
name


looking_for (pivot between user and gender)
-----------
id
user_id
gender_id
```

`looking_for` is a pivot table between `user` and `gender`. A user can date multiple genders.  eg. A female having interest in dating males as well as females.

`user` has `hasOne` with `user_profile`

```
public function profileDetails(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\UserProfile');
}
```

Inversly, `user_profile` has  'belongsTo' relation with `user`

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}
```

`user_profile` has `belongsTo` relation with `gender` because each user profile has a gender

```
public function gender(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Gender');
}
```

`user` and `gender` has `belongsToMany` via `looking_for` because a user can set his dating preference to multiple genders.

```
// User
public function lookingFor(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Gender', 'looking_for')->withTimestamps();
}

//Gender
public function lookedUpBy(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'looking_for')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now, i'm trying to create a search.

eg. A female is looking to date both males and females living in US. Also have to consider that the males and females(that will be shown in the result) have set their `looking_for` to female.

First, I'm trying to fetch all users who have set their `looking_for` preference to female.

```
Gender::with('lookedUpBy')->find($genderIdOfSearchedUser);
```

How to filter it down further?

### Edit

i have moved `gender_id` to `users` table as it is better suited there.

I have an interests table as well

```
interests (1-on-1 Dating, Online Friends, Swingers etc)
---------
id
name
```

and a pivot table between `users` and `interests`

```
interest_user
-------------
id
interest_id
user_id
```

So, a user can look up for multiple genders having similar interests.

Say, a female is looking to date both males and females living in US, having interest in `1-on-1 Dating` and `Online Friends`

Comment: why is gender a own entity?

Comment: because a user can set its preference to date multiple genders.

Comment: Its just my opinion, but i think there is no need for the separation. Every user has just one gender, so you can put `gender` to your users table.
You could add a `interests` table or something like that ?! Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: i already have an `interests` table. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gordon's answer will work, but you're basically pulling all the data from the database and iterating on the object collection nitpicking for your answer in program memory instead of leveraging your database engine, which is built for these kind of queries. 
I would use laravel [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method to query the many to many relatiobship

```
//assuming you are in the User instance you are trying to search for
$user = User::first();
$userGenderPref = $user->lookingFor()->get()->lists('gender_id');
$userInterestedIn = $user->interestedIn()->get()->lists('interest_id');
$results = User::whereHas('lookingFor', function($query) use ($userPref){//looking for gender
      $query->whereIn('gender_id',$userPref);
})
->whereHas('interestedIn', function($query) use ($userInterestedIn){//interested in
      $query->whereIn('interest_id',$userInterestedIn);
})
->where('user_id','!=',$user->user_id)//this is added to filter out our current user
->where('country_id',$user->country_id) //same country code as the original user
->get();
```

the above code will return a list of users that have the same preferences as your user, gender and interest and it will also make sure it's in teh same country as current user.

Comment: you mean you want to look in the `belongToMany` User relationship with interest and add country code to the query?

Comment: updated my answer. had to invent the interests relationship function (the `interestedIn` )

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has nice [collection filters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-each) ;)

Try something like this:

```
$collection = Gender::with('lookingFor')->each(function($gender) {

  // get the lookingFor names
  $looking_for = $gender->lookingFor()->lists('name');

  // check if your case has been met
  if(in_array('Female', $looking_for)) return $gender;
});
```

Be warned, it's pseudocode ;)

---

Ps. If you want to learn more about `Laravel Collections`, here is a [free ebook](https://leanpub.com/laravelcollectionsunraveled/) which i can highly recommend.